# Disabled Display Adapter and Boots Properly, now what?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I disabled the display adapter using the device manager on my win7 via safe-mode and now my computer boots up find instead of going black after splash (e.g. login screen). I downloaded and updated my driver for my video card (ati radeon 6950). I just bought the computer this week. ALL signs point to the graphics card as being the culprit of all my problems...what can I do to fix this?! Thanks.

Comment: This is really confusingly worded.  What's the problem?  You don't get any video after the BIOS splash screen (or the Windows splash screen)?  Was it working properly when you got it?  If so, when was the last time it worked?

Comment: I'd be tempted to take it back to the shop where you bought it from. A week old computer should work.

Comment: Problem is: I cannot boot up properly without disabling the display adapter. If it is enabled, when it gets to the login screen the monitor loses connection (I do hear the chime however).